# dynamic algorithm to find optimal solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

considering a game bored with white and red squares ordered as followed:

( start w w w w w w r r w w w w r w r w r w finish )

w = white.
r = red.

there are 3 buttons.
green button: move 5 steps.
yellow button: move 3 steps.
blue button: move 3 steps.

game rules:
- if a players land on a red square lose.
- first player finish the game win.
- land on white square is allowed.

greedy algorithm :

```
x = 0 
steps = 0
stop = false
while (....)
if a[x+5] is white then
 push the green buttton and x= x+5, steps++
if a[x+3] is white then
 push the yellow buttton and x= x+3, steps++
if a[x+2] is white then
 push the blue buttton and x= x+2, steps++
else stop = true
```

required: the minimum steps to win the game.

by following the greedy algorithm above the solution will be 552225 whereas the optimal solution is 33555.

my question is how to apply dynamic algorithm to find the optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is produce an array that contains min-cost and best previous move.  You fill it up from the beginning to the end, and then you read the optimal solution from the end to the start.  So like this:

```
min_cost = [infinite for all steps]
arriving_move = [none for all steps]
For each i in 0 to steps-1:
    if square[i] = 'r':
        pass
    else:
       for j in 2, 3, 5:
           if i <= j:
               if min_cost[i-j] + 1 < min_cost[i]:
                   min_cost[i] = min_cost[i-j] + 1
                   arriving_move[i] = j
reversed_answer = []
i = steps-1
while arriving_move[i] is not none:
    reversed_answer.append(arriving_move[i])
    i = i - arriving_move[i]
answer = reversed(reversed_answer)
```

Note, this will find an optimal game where you arrive directly on the finish.  In your example the moves will therefore come out 33553.

If you're OK with "overshooting the mark", you'll have to add a special end node with its own special rules at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea:** Think backward. Assume you're in `i`. What are the options to reach this cell?

```
// Assume cell[i] = min number of moves to last cell starting from this cell

cell[n] = 0 //finish cell
cell[0..n-1] = ∞

for i = n to 1
  cell[i-1] = min(cell[i-1], cell[i]+1) //if cell[i-1] not red
  cell[i-3] = min(cell[i-1], cell[i]+1) //if cell[i-3] not red
  cell[i-5] = min(cell[i-1], cell[i]+1) //if cell[i-5] not red
```

In the end, the value of `cell[0]` shows the minimum steps needed to finish the game.

Answer (score 0):

To reach finish, you should have first landed on either

`finish - 5` or `finish - 3` or `finish - 2` and then from there do 1 more button click to reach the `finish`.

The recursive formula for this :

`minSteps(end) = 1 + Math.min( minSteps(end-5), Math.min(minSteps(end-2), minSteps(end-3)) )`

You could code this like in (Java) with memoization:

```
private static int minSteps( int start, int end, String s ) {
    if ( end < start ) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if ( end == start ) return 0;
    if ( s.charAt(end) == 'r' ) {
      dp[end] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      return dp[end];
    }
    if ( dp[end] != -1 ) return dp[end];
    int stepTwo = minSteps( start, end - 2, s );
    int stepThree = minSteps( start, end - 3, s);
    int stepFive = minSteps( start, end - 5, s );
    int min = Math.min( Math.min( stepTwo, stepThree ), stepFive );
    if ( min != Integer.MAX_VALUE ) {
      dp[end] = 1 + min;
    } else {
      dp[end] = min;
    }
    return dp[end];
}
```

For the input : `w w w w w w r r w w w w r w r w r w` the resulting `dp` array would be:

`[-1, 2147483647, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2147483647, 3, 2147483647, 3, -1, 4]` and answer is 4 : `18 -> 16 -> 11 -> 6 -> 1`

then you could build your jumps from the end by following the `dp` array.